# Issue displaying nested values in list - Lightning Component

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

I have got a nested soql query which appears to be giving my values into the List as intended:

[image]

But when I go to display it in my lightning component all the is being displayed is the outer Select statement.

[image]

AddTransactions.cmp

```
    <aura:component controller="AddTransactionsController" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId" access="global">
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
   <aura:attribute name="ListOfContract" type="Contract[]"/>
   <ul>
      <aura:iteration items="{!v.ListOfContract}" var="con">
         <li type="dice">Contract Number : {!con.ContractNumber}</li>
         <ul>
            <aura:iteration items="{!con.Assets}" var="ass" indexVar="index">
               <li>Asset {!index + 1} Name : {!ass.Name}</li>
            </aura:iteration>
         </ul>
         <hr/>
      </aura:iteration>
   </ul>    
</aura:component>
```

AddTransactions.js

```
    ({
    doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
      //call apex class method
      var action = component.get('c.fetchContract');
      action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
       //store state of response
       var state = response.getState();
       if (state === "SUCCESS") {
        //set response value in ListOfAccount attribute on component.
           console.log('response : ' + response.getReturnValue());
        component.set('v.ListOfContract', response.getReturnValue());
       }
      });
      $A.enqueueAction(action);
     },
})
```

AddTransactionsController

```
    public class AddTransactionsController {
    @AuraEnabled
 public static list <Contract> fetchContract() {
  // query 10 records from account with their relevant contacts and return query.
  List <Contract> lstOfCon = [SELECT id, contractnumber, merchant_account__c,
                              (SELECT id, name from assets__r),
                              (SELECT id, name from transactions__r)
                              from contract LIMIT 100];
     System.debug('conlist' + lstOfCon);
    return lstOfCon;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the correct, case-sensitive name. Since the relationship is named "Assets__r", you need to use the same name in your component:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!con.Assets__r}" var="asset" indexVar="index">
```

P.S. Shortening "asset" to the first three letters might not be the best idea, as some people consider that word offensive.